# How To Get Blogger's Popular Post Widget To Measure 1 Day of Stats

Tags: blogger

Is there a way to get Blogger's popular post gadget to measure just one day of stats? I use Blogger's new Emporio template and can tweak code in the HTML. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that since Blogger Popular post widget only have 7 days minimum range of Popular Posts. Also there's  no API or Json provided by Blogger for Popular Post data, so you can't do that.

Maybe you can send Feedback to Blogger via Feedback button. Make request this feature.

OR optional

You should have self hosting. Then put tracker code at your Blogger posts, and then send pageviews counter data from your Blogger posts. Then store this pageviews data in your database. From it you can provide opular post widget API or iframe widget base on 1 days range time.

Comment: Feedback button! Forgot about that, thanks. I need a 1-day popular post widget because sometimes popular news from 7-days ago gets stuck on my widget, which is confusing to readers.